# changing default value for one column in SQL 5.7 gives warning about other column

Tags: sql, mysqli

Since SQL 5.7, my customers get more problems. One of the issues I found was following:

When I run a query, I get a message about another column, that is really strange?? who can explain this?

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE advertisement ALTER COLUMN local_name set default 'x';
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'end_time'
```

The table which created this error is following:

```
mysql> show columns from advertisement;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| local_name     | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| chinese_name   | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| image          | varchar(128) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| top1           | varchar(128) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| center1        | varchar(128) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| bottom1        | varchar(128) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| bottom2        | varchar(128) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| bottom3        | varchar(128) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| top_colour1    | varchar(16)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| center_colour1 | varchar(16)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| bottom_colour1 | varchar(16)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| bottom_colour2 | varchar(16)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| bottom_colour3 | varchar(16)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| start_time     | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| end_time       | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| hour           | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |                     |                |
| status         | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because of server SQL Mode - `NO_ZERO_DATE`.

From the reference: `NO_ZERO_DATE` - In strict mode, don't allow `'0000-00-00'` as a valid date. You can still insert zero dates with the `IGNORE` option. When not in strict mode, the date is accepted but a warning is generated.

[Documentation link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)

Comment: Solution: I changed the entire project (34 sql tables) in using strict mode.. somehow the strict mode is suddenly switching on again and shit happens in the database. Now after all the code is using more strict things, I hope restaurants will get faith back in my Linux POS software. :-)